# Java this в конструкторе

Tags: java, this, конструктор

При изучении книги Герберта Шилдта наткнулся на следующий пример:

```
class MyThread implements Runnable {
    Thread thrd;

    MyThread(String name) {
        thrd = new Thread(this, name);
    }
 ...
}
```

Непонятен фрагмент с созданием объекта `Thread`, где используется `this`. Мне кажется нелогичным передача `this` в качестве аргумента, ведь сам объект вроде как еще не создан, раз мы находимся в конструкторе.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с данным противоречием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В момент работы конструктора объект уже создан, просто еще не проинициализирован. Поэтому использование `this` в конструкторе вполне допустимо.

В передаче `this` аргументом куда-нибудь тоже нет ничего противозаконного, т. к. объект передаётся по ссылке, и все изменения, произведенные в нем в ходе дальнейшей работы конструктора, будут видны там, куда вы его передаете.